# Spark filter multiple group of rows to a single row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to acheive the following,

Lets say I have a dataframe with the following columns

```
id  | name  | alias
-------------------
1   | abc   | short
1   | abc   | ailas-long-1
1   | abc   | another-long-alias
2   | xyz   | short_alias
2   | xyz   | same_length
3   | def   | alias_1
```

I want to groupby id and name and select the shorter alias,

The output I am expecting is

```
id  | name  | alias
-------------------
1   | abc   | short
2   | xyz   | short_alias
3   | def   | alias_1
```

I can achevie this using window and row_number, is there anyother efficient method to get the same result. In general, the thrid column filter condition can be anything in this case its the length of the field.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: looking at your expected dataframe it seems that simple filter would do the trick . `df.filter(df['alias'] == 'short-alias')`

Comment: No, those are samples, there can be any value. I will edit the question to  make it clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is use `length` inbuilt function and use that in `window` function as

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy('id', 'name').orderBy('length')

df.withColumn('length', f.length('alias'))\
    .withColumn('length', f.row_number().over(windowSpec))\
    .filter(f.col('length') == 1)\
    .drop('length')\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+---+----+-----------+
|id |name|alias      |
+---+----+-----------+
|3  |def |alias_1    |
|1  |abc |short      |
|2  |xyz |short_alias|
+---+----+-----------+
```

Comment: Whats the use of window in your code above, I couldn't see its usage.

Comment: Thanks, I used the approach you mentioned earlier of using row_number, because I needed the last column to be of shortest in length. If I use first, it will not ensure that its always of shorter length. I was wondering if there are any other methods.

Comment: yeah you are absolutely correct @Murali. My mistake again. I have updated my answer for you to accept and upvote. :) thanks. I think this is the best approach I have in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

A solution without window (Not very pretty..) and the easiest, in my opinion, rdd solution:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hiveCtx = HiveContext(sc)

rdd = sc.parallelize([(1   , "abc"   , "short-alias"),
                     (1   , "abc"   , "short"),
                         (1   , "abc"   , "ailas-long-1"),
                         (1   , "abc"   , "another-long-alias"),
                         (2   , "xyz"   , "same_length"),
                         (2   , "xyz"   , "same_length1"),
                         (3   , "def"   , "short_alias") ])

df = hiveCtx.createDataFrame(\
rdd, ["id", "name", "alias"])

len_df = df.groupBy(["id", "name"]).agg(F.min(F.length("alias")).alias("alias_len"))

df = df.withColumn("alias_len", F.length("alias"))

cond = ["alias_len", "id", "name"]

df.join(len_df, cond).show()

print rdd.map(lambda x: ((x[0], x[1]), x[2]))\
    .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x if len(x) < len(y) else y ).collect()
```

Output:

```
+---------+---+----+-----------+
|alias_len| id|name|      alias|
+---------+---+----+-----------+
|       11|  3| def|short_alias|
|       11|  2| xyz|same_length|
|        5|  1| abc|      short|
+---------+---+----+-----------+

[((2, 'xyz'), 'same_length'), ((3, 'def'), 'short_alias'), ((1, 'abc'), 'short')]
```